# What is a good beginner's book to read to get a greater understanding of neuroscience?

Tags: study-cognitive-sciences

Having read "the mind that changes itself," i've become interested in neuroscience. However reading discussions about this book online there does appear to be controversy about the book and the author doesn't appear to be an actual neuroscientist as well as many scathing reviews online. It still was a good read and factual (i think?). However the actual subject i find very interesting. I was wondering if anyone could suggest a more respected book to give a good introduction, or any good resources to learn from.

Comment: This is a pretty broad question as neuroscience is a rather broad field. Would you mind specifying what questions in particular you want answered?

Comment: I completely realise this however since i've only recently discovered the subject don't really know what areas exist. I was looking for introductory texts then find specifics from there.

Comment: If you want a quick overview of how people try to build brain models, I would recommend "How to Build a Brain", other than that I mostly just get my neuroscience news by following a bunch of neuroscientists on Twitter...

Comment: I still think this question is too broad. If you elaborated on the controversy and specified the specific things that are controversial and what you don't understand about them, we could answer those questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try this one: 30-Second Brain: The 50 Most Mind-blowing Ideas in Neuroscience, Each Explained in Half a Minute. ISBN-10: 184831647X. I haven't read it myself but it covers a really wide spectrum: single neurons, neural networks, brain architecture, awareness, perception, disease, ageing, etc. 
Importantly it's written by really good scientists in who are all currently doing really interesting things.